# Is there a faster and object orientated alternative to SDL for C++?

Tags: c++, sdl, libraries

The current version of libsdl (1.2.x branch) is very, very slow with blending and per pixel alpha (as it uses software blending). Is there any other good alternative to it?

Comment: I think this was harshly closed, the comments and answers are civilized and it is an interesting question with an excellent answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

SFML is exactly what you need: http://sfml-dev.org/.

Skim through the tutorials, you'll see that it's way easier and more powerful than SDL.

Comment: As far as I can see from the examples, it's simply brilliant... though it will take some time to get used to it...

Answer (score 6):

There is SFML : http://www.sfml-dev.org/

Answer (score 2):

Or... just use OpenGL on top of SDL.

Answer (score 1):

GLFW. It only tries to do one thing (window creation/input handling). It is C based and pretty easy to use provides bindings for several languages.

SFML does all that and also provides an API for audio, fonts, and networking. It's nativity a C++ API but provides bindings for several languages.

There are other thousands of options: SDL (older), Unity and UDK if you want to create a game, ...